# Website Layout in rows

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website that acts as a frame to another HTML page.
The layout I want is a section for the site title and below the main part which has an object nested inside a section (There should be more than one, when only one is visible, so this structure is important).
For some reason on Firefox I'm seeing it as I wanted to, but on Chrome the "object" just won't spread on 100% height.

The Code:

```css
body {
 margin-left: 0%;
 margin-right: 0%;
 height: 100vh;
 margin-top: 0%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 z-index: 0;
}

.site-title {
 height: 50px;
}

.main-menu {
 position: fixed;
 display: inline-block;
}

.main {
 height: auto;
 flex-grow: 1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

section {
 border: 5px solid pink;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 overflow: hidden;
 flex-grow: 1;
 height: auto;
}

object {
 border: 5px solid #FFFFFF; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="site-title"> 
  <h1>Strawberry</h1>
 </div>
 
 <div class="main" id="main">
  <section class="instance">
      <object data="home.html"></object>
  </section>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm in Chrome. It works as desired for me. Try adding `min-height:100%` to your `.object`

Comment: The snippet appears empty to me. Btw if you want anything to have height 100%, you'll need everything above to have it too, starting from html, body, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object element can not be assign with percentage values for his height and width attributes (only pixels are allowed).

If you wish to use percentage to enable a responsive solution, you can bind object with CSS inline (e.g: `<object style="height:100%">`) or in a stylesheet (e.g: main.css -> `object {height:100%}`)

Notice: all parents elements of object must be set to 100% as well.